# How to efficiently query database when doing counts in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

So what I want to do is to create a function that I can run, that will do various counts to tally up different results

Now in my head what I want to do is to select all from the table in a database, and then use php to sort through it and do various counts from the same results, that way the database is not being queried too much, but I have no idea how to even begin or even if that's possible.

The alternate would be just doing individual queries which i can do, but will be really in efficient, especially if i want to to many different counts.

Comment: if you want to count anything, use the database, it will be far more efficient than PHP

Comment: If you can do it in a query it should be much faster.  Can you give an example of the things you are trying to count?

Comment: I want to count things such as total items submitted for each user in another table, total items in database items/per category etc... - Mainly statistics, but alto of them.

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as count from pm where ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
$result = $result['count'];------This line asignes the $count var, and you create it actually when you add the "as count " into the query.  $result=$result['count']; goes after the query.